# Facebook like button reacts on all posts

Tags: wordpress, facebook-like

I think something's wrong with my query I'm using below. I want to show multiple thumbnails with each its own like button. All works fine, but when you press 1 button, it will like all other images as well. Tried the reset query, but I guess it's not working or I got things wrong. Someone got a simular problem or knows how to fix this?

```
        <?php query_posts('cat=1'); ?>
        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php $thumb = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumb', $single = true); ?>
            <ul>
                <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="View <?php the_title(); ?>'s showcase"><img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" alt="View <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>'s showcase" width="150" height="111" /></a>  
                    <div class="design"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="View <?php the_title(); ?>'s showcase"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                    <div class="subtitle"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">view feature</a></div>
                    <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
                    <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
                    <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- AddThis Button END --> 
                </li>
            </ul>
        <?php endwhile; ?>    
        <?php else : ?>    
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query() ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a fbml href attribute to the like button.

```
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count" fb:like:href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
```